# Cakephp route and prefix

Tags: cakephp, view, router, prefix

I have a problem with Routes in CakePHP. Let me explain.

I'm using authentication through the `Auth` component. I have a routing prefix called `account`.

When I want to edit a user, I'm calling the users controller which gives me a URL like:

```
/account/users/edit/5
```

What I want is to have a URL like:

```
/account/edit/5
```

So I changed my router like this:

```
Router::connect('/:prefix/edit/:id',
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'edit'),
    array('pass' => array('id'), 'id' => '[0-9]+')
);
```

which worked when I try to access `/account/edit/5`

My problem is located in my view. How can I access this route using the `Html->link` helper?

So far, I'm just doing it like this:

```
'/'.$this->Session->read('Auth.User.role').'/edit/'.$this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')
```

But it's not really clean in my opinion. I want to use the helper.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Do you always want that URL to start with 'account', regardless of the users role?

Comment: No, url start with account, when user has an `account` type, otherwise, it will be the other prefix

Answer (score 1):

Using a prefix "account" would mean needing an action like "account_edit" in your controller. That's probably not what you want. Also why put the "id" in url when it's already there in the session? Why not just use url "/account" for all users and get the id (and role if required) from session in the action?

```
Router::connect('/account',
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'edit')
);
```

This would be the clean way to generate required url:

```
$this->Html->link('Account', array(
    'controller' => 'users',
    'action' => 'edit'
));
// Will return url "/account"
```

In general always use array form to specify url to benefit from reverse routing.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the hit about the id in session, you're right. About the link, since the account `type` (prefixe) is account, the url  `/account` is link to the user dashboard. To edit, I want to use `/account/edit`. For the router I know how to do, but it's to make it match with the html helper. Thanks

Comment: Okay so use route as needed and to get link specify the url as the eg. i gave. Assuming the route you are using is the same as what you originally showed just add `'prefix' => 'account'` to the url array in the helper usage eg. I showed.

Comment: Nope, it's still not working. It's creating a link like `/account/users/edit`. Don't understand why it can't reverse the url

Comment: Show again the route you have set.

Comment: here is my route `Router::connect('/:prefix/edit', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'edit'));`

Comment: Well then this url `array('prefix' => 'account', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'edit')` with the helper should return `/account/edit`.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, I've already try this in my helper but unfortunately, it does not give me `/account/edit` and that's why I don't understand.It may come from a conflict with my other Routes???

Answer (score 0):

everything is just fine except router. it should be

```
Router::connect('/account/*',
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'edit')
);
```

and creating anchor link in various way using Helper you can [CHECK HERE](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html)